# Excel 2013 Column Width Does Not Copy To New Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-office-2013

EDIT 2:  If i wasn't clear in the original post I have tried copying the entire sheet.  I have tried copy-paste special - column width. As noted in a comment below, I have tried every way to copy and paste a sheet or column width in excel 2013.  This is not the problem.

ORIGINAL.

I am trying to copy an entire sheet within a workbook.  All data is in a table, which seems to copy just fine, but all of the columns are the same width and not the widths they are on the original sheet.

I tried copying to a new workbook, same result.

I tried copying and pasting by selecting the data on the orginal and past-special - column width on the new sheet.  This didn't work.

I manually changed one column width, then did the above and the width changed back to the smaller width.

The width on the original Column A for example is 12.71, the width on all columns on the new sheet are 8.43

I don't have many columns and could adjust them all manually, but I would really love to know the root problem here, which may be me.

This is Office 2013 on Windows 7.  Everything is Fully updated as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:  I have tried removing all table formatting and this didn't help anything either.

I copied another sheet with table formatting in the workbook.  The first column changed width to 8.43 as above, but the rest of the sheet was a perfect copy.

Comment: you can use paste special Column width

Comment: I have tried that, as my original post notes, with no success.

Comment: After pasting the data select the new one and use Paste Special Column width it will work

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  Read my post please.

Comment: You need to copy the whole sheet, not just the content. If you right click the name of the sheet, Move or Copy..., and select "Create a copy", it will copy values, format, etc.

Comment: How did you copy? did you use move or copy sheet?

Comment: I have tried all of the above.  I have copied the entire sheet.  I have copied only one column.  I have paste special - column width.  I have copied and pasted every possible way one can copy and paste a sheet or column in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to right-click on the tab you want to copy then select (move or copy) and you must tick the box create a copy, click ok and it will do it and you will have the same tab name with a (2) after it. Hope this helps.